Why is SRAM/Quarq Drop-In BB Power Meter not Compatible with Cannondale Asymmetric Integration?
I have a Canondale SuperSix EVO SE gravel bike (2023), which features Cannondale Asymmetric Integration (Ai) technology.
The drivetrain is SRAM Rival eTap AXS and the crankset appears to be compatible with this drop-in power meter, except that SRAM's product page says it is compatible with all DUB bottom brackets "except Ai."
I understood Ai was just about the dishing of the rear wheel... can somebody help me understand why this would affect the compatibility of a BB or crankset power meter?

It can be done. I will provide some detail in an answer tomorrow morning.

The thing with the Asymmetric Integration (AI) standard is that the entire drivetrain is offset 6mm to the right. Their stated rationale is that this improved tire clearance without needing to lengthen the chainstays. The downside is that you need a longer crank spindle. If you Google, I believe you should see Cannondale stock replacement AI-specific spindles for its own cranks, and you should see that SRAM makes AI-specific cranks and BBs. I believe SRAM's cranksets aren't modular, so you can't just replace the spindle (and you'd also need to have an offset chainring, I believe). Here is one SRAM document that lists AI and non-AI spacer requirements.
This Reddit post confirms that standard SRAM cranks aren't compatible with AI frames. This YouTube video corroborates that on MTBs, you can't swap in a different crank type.
Cannondale has kicked off a bunch of innovation in the bike world with its alternative standards. However, with AI, you needed specific cranks and BBs. Replacement wheels had to be dished left. I don't know how many riders and mechanics would say that this really was worth the tradeoffs. Cannondale seems to be moving away from this.

I wonder why the crank spindle necessarily needs to be longer. Do AI bikes have longer BB shells (why?)?

@MaplePanda if I understand correctly, shifting the entire drive-train to the right by 6mm would indeed require that the bb and crank spindle be 6mm wider.

I have also been wondering why. I am guessing it might have to do with maintaining a symmetric pedal position.

@chiashurb Oh yeah that makes sense. In my mind I thought Cannondale just moved the rear only and left the cranks where they normally are, but I realized that would give you a horrible chain line on the smallest cogs.

@MaplePanda yeah that had been my thinking too, until I read the answer above.

You may need "Road Ai" cranks but basically, once you have SRAM or Quarq cranks that can accept the Quarq power spider, you bolt it in and follow the instructions.
https://support.quarq.com/hc/en-us/articles/10418735152795-How-do-I-upgrade-my-SRAM-RED-or-Force-AXS-crankset-with-Cannondale-Ai-spacing-to-a-power-meter
On the DUB bb chart, for the Road Ai crankset, that's a 6mm left spacer and 9mm right. Which sounds big, but it's on the chart.
https://docs.sram.com/en-US/publications/7unL17qdyCWxTL38aPmYJ0/UM%20-%20DUB%20Cranksets%20and%20Bottom%20Brackets#hashItem=dub-road-bottom-bracket-spacer-chart
As long as you have SRAM cranks suitable for your BB, the Quarq unit is a bolt-in upgrade.
You can also take off the SRAM Non drive side adjuster and use "traditional" BB30 spacers and a wavy washer to make further chainline adjustments. This is undocumented but some Cannondale bikes with BB30A were supplied from the factory with this modification. I would suggest you have to know what you are doing and what you are aiming for when you take this route.

I just realised you want to use the tiny power meter. My answer doesn't really help you in this case. Sorry!

Honestly the suggestion to use the spider instead is quite helpful!
